# I need replacing upload component with defoult mesh in dash

Tags: python, upload

The code will take a mash with upload component, instead I am going to set a defoult mesh and remove the upload mesh component.

```
def create_input_mesh(name):
    """Create input mesh components."""
    comp_id = name.replace(".", "-")
    return (
        dcc.Upload(
            id=comp_id,
            children=html.Div([dbc.Button("Select file(s)...", color="light")]),
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True,
        ),
        (State(comp_id, "contents"), State(comp_id, "filename")),
    )
```

This is a code for component and the below is for using it.

```
input_element_options = config.get("app_input_options", {})

    fixed_inputs = config.get("fixed_inputs", {})

    input_order = []
    input_elements = []
    input_dependencies = []


    for input_var, input_type in get_input_types().items():
        nc_type = get_type_by_name(input_type["type"])
        if input_var in fixed_inputs:
            continue

        if is_geometry_type(nc_type):
            elem, input_dep = create_input_mesh(input_var)
```

Here more functions that works with mesh if needed.

```
def is_geometry_type(nc_type):
    """

    Args:
        nc_type: python class

    Returns: bool whether the given class is a geometric nc type.

    """
    return issubclass(nc_type, PointCloud3D) or issubclass(nc_type, MultiMesh)


def read_geometry_type(
    list_of_contents, list_of_filenames, nc_type, interpreter, loader, **kwargs
):
    """Read geometric nc type.

    Args:
        list_of_contents: list of contents as uploaded from api.
        list_of_filenames: list of uploaded filenames.
        nc_type: nc_type object.
        **kwargs:

    Returns: dict of numpy arrays.

    """
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
        for content, filename in zip(list_of_contents, list_of_filenames):
            _, content_string = content.split(",")
            decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
            with open(Path(tmpdirname).joinpath(filename), "wb") as f:
                f.write(decoded)
        if len(list_of_contents) == 1:
            list_of_filenames = list_of_filenames[0]
        return nc_type.read(
            list_of_filenames,
            root=tmpdirname,
            interpreter=interpreter,
            loader=loader,
            **kwargs
        ).to_numpy()
```

I tried to use Input component instead of upload but it did not work.

```
def create_input_mesh(name, default_filename="apps/lse-tf1/geometry_0000.stl"):
    """Create input mesh components."""
    comp_id = name.replace(".", "-")
    
    # Check if a default filename is provided, otherwise set to None
    initial_filename = default_filename if default_filename else None
    
    return (
        dcc.Input(
            id=comp_id,
            type='text',
            value=initial_filename,
            disabled=True,  # Disable the input to prevent user editing
            style={'width': '50%'},  # Adjust the width as needed
        ),
        (State(comp_id, "contents"), State(comp_id, "filename")),
    )
```